# missing values NaN

Tags: r, nan, knn

please help me, there's an error when i'm trying to make output with testing data 10% (training data 90) with 1000 times simulation.

```
#pemanggilan paket yang digunakan
library(caret)
library(KernelKnn)

#perhitungan akurasi prediksi dengan 100 kali simulasi
sim = function(B, p1, k1)
{
  hasileu = matrix(0, B, 4)
  for (i in 1:B)
  {
    #memanggil data boston
    boston = MASS::Boston

    #membagi data train dan data test
    indexes = createDataPartition(boston$medv, p = p1, list = F)
    train = boston[indexes, ]
    test = boston[-indexes, ]
    
    train_x = train[, -14]
    train_x = scale(train_x)[,]
    train_y = train[,14]
    
    test_x = test[, -14]
    test_x = scale(test[,-14])[,]
    test_y = test[,14]
    
    #model prediksi regresi KNN
    pred1 = KernelKnn(train_x, TEST_data = test_x, train_y, k = k1, method = 'euclidean', weights_function = NULL, regression = T)

    #perhitungan akurasi
    mse = mean((test_y - pred1)^2)
    mae = mean(abs(test_y - pred1))
    rmse = sqrt(mse)
    mape = mean(abs((test_y - pred1)/test_y))
    r2 = cor(test_y, pred1)^2
    hasileu[i,1] = rmse
    hasileu[i,2] = mape
    hasileu[i,3] = mae
    hasileu[i,4] = r2
  }
  return(apply(hasileu, 2, mean))
}

#penentuan rentang nilai K
hitung.variasi.k = function(B,p,K)
{
  has11 = matrix(0,K,4)
  for (i in 1:K)
  {
    has11[i,] = sim(B,p,i)
  }
  has11
}

#hasil akurasi berbagai proporsi data uji
K = 10
has11 = hitung.variasi.k(1000, 0.9,K)

Error in KernelKnn(train_x, TEST_data = test_x, train_y, k = k1, method = "euclidean", : 
the TEST_data includes missing values
```

Comment: If you add `dplyr::count(test_x, chas)` right after you define it, you'll see the breakdown of the counts of each category of that variable before using `KernelKnn()`. It turns out that the `chas` variable doesn't have many `1` cases. One of the partitions that gets created therefore only has `0`, and you're getting into an error because that variable has no variance.

Comment: can you show me where I should add dplyr::count(test_x, chas) ?? I still don't get it

Comment: is it related to type of CHAS variable?

Comment: After `test_x = test[, -14]`. I may just be spitballing here and perhaps I'm wrong, but shouldn't you scale on the whole data set before the partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

the following code uses tryCatch to catch 'error' and continue the exeuction to the end.

```
library(caret) 
library(KernelKnn)

#perhitungan akurasi prediksi dengan 100 kali simulasi
sim = function(B, p1, k1)
{
  hasileu = matrix(0, B, 4)
  for (i in 1:B)
  {
    #memanggil data boston
    boston = MASS::Boston
    
    #membagi data train dan data test
    indexes = createDataPartition(boston$medv, p = p1, list = F)
    train = boston[indexes, ]
    test = boston[-indexes, ]
    
    train_x = train[, -14]
    train_x = scale(train_x)[,]
    train_y = train[,14]
    
    test_x = test[, -14]
    test_x = scale(test[,-14])[,]
    test_y = test[,14]
    
    errorFlag=0
    #model prediksi regresi KNN
    pred1 =tryCatch(
     KernelKnn(train_x, TEST_data = test_x, train_y, k = k1, method = 'euclidean', weights_function = NULL, regression = T)
    , error=function(e) 
      { print(e); print(paste("error at loop", i));errorFlag<<-1;}
    )

    if (errorFlag==0)
    {
      #perhitungan akurasi
      mse = mean((test_y - pred1)^2)
      mae = mean(abs(test_y - pred1))
      rmse = sqrt(mse)
      mape = mean(abs((test_y - pred1)/test_y))
      r2 = cor(test_y, pred1)^2
      hasileu[i,1] = rmse
      hasileu[i,2] = mape
      hasileu[i,3] = mae
      hasileu[i,4] = r2
    }
  }
  return(apply(hasileu, 2, mean))
}

#penentuan rentang nilai K
hitung.variasi.k = function(B,p,K)
{
  has11 = matrix(0,K,4)
  for (i in 1:K)
  {
    has11[i,] = sim(B,p1=p,k1=i)
  }
  return(has11)
}

#hasil akurasi berbagai proporsi data uji
K = 10
has11 = hitung.variasi.k(B=1000, p=0.9,K=10)
```

Comment: do you know what's causing my error? i still don't get it why we have to add errorFlag and tryCatch in your answer. but thank you anyway.

Comment: The data is (randomly?) generated each time but in some simulation the data distribution may not be produced it a way that KernelKnn can handle. Stackoverflow is about coding and I will not an expert of KernelKnn. As far as the code is concerned, please consider to accept as the answer. Thanks,

Comment: i have run your program and it works i can see value of has11. but there's still an error in LOOPING. so i think that my program is not perfect, i mean maybe there's something wrong in it. can you identify that? anyway, thank you for your response.

Comment: It is not coding error. It is all about data. I fixed the code without looking the data distribution etc. As mentioned, stackoverflow is about coding. You executed the program sometimes working because the program does not work sometimes. If you run the program manually as a loop, you will see the error. Again it is data generated causing the error and each time the data is different.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this error you have to find out if the 'train_x' or 'test_x' include any NA's and if it's an option for you to skip this specific iteration. The 'KernelKnn' package does not allow missing values for the [train, test or y values](https://github.com/mlampros/KernelKnn/blob/master/R/kernelknn.R#L58-L59)

The following code snippet (adjusted based on your code) skips the iteration where either the 'train_x' or 'test_x' includes missing values. The while-for loop accounts for the cases where NA's are present and returns only if your matrix has "B" number of rows

```
#pemanggilan paket yang digunakan
library(caret)
library(KernelKnn)

#perhitungan akurasi prediksi dengan 100 kali simulasi
sim = function(B, p1, k1)
{
  hasileu = matrix(0, B, 4)
  increment = 1
  
  while(TRUE) {
    
    if (increment == B + 1) break
    
    #memanggil data boston
    boston = MASS::Boston
    
    #membagi data train dan data test
    indexes = createDataPartition(boston$medv, p = p1, list = F)
    train = boston[indexes, ]
    test = boston[-indexes, ]
    
    train_x = train[, -14]
    train_x = scale(train_x)[,]
    train_y = train[,14]
    
    test_x = test[, -14]
    test_x = scale(test[,-14])[,]
    test_y = test[,14]
    
    # checks for NA's and skips in case train_x or test_x include any
    NAs_train = sum(colSums(is.na(train_x)))
    NAs_tess = sum(colSums(is.na(test_x)))
    
    if (any(c(NAs_train > 0, NAs_tess > 0))) {
      next
    }
    else {
      
      #model prediksi regresi KNN
      pred1 = KernelKnn(train_x, TEST_data = test_x, train_y, k = k1, method = 'euclidean', weights_function = NULL, regression = T)
      
      #perhitungan akurasi
      mse = mean((test_y - pred1)^2)
      mae = mean(abs(test_y - pred1))
      rmse = sqrt(mse)
      mape = mean(abs((test_y - pred1)/test_y))
      r2 = cor(test_y, pred1)^2
      hasileu[increment,1] = rmse
      hasileu[increment,2] = mape
      hasileu[increment,3] = mae
      hasileu[increment,4] = r2
      
      increment = increment + 1
    }
  }

  # return(hasileu)                    # verify that you receive B rows by replacing the next line by this line
  return(apply(hasileu, 2, mean))
}

#penentuan rentang nilai K
hitung.variasi.k = function(B,p,K)
{
  has11 = matrix(0,K,4)
  for (i in 1:K)
  {
    has11[i,] = sim(B,p,i)
  }
  has11
}

#hasil akurasi berbagai proporsi data uji
K = 10
has11 = hitung.variasi.k(1000, 0.9,K)
str(has11)
```

For the record I'm the author of the KernelKnn package.